# How to get child component's data in VueJs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This is an easy question but I dont know the best way to do it correctly with Vue2:

**Parent Component:**

```vue
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <child></child>
    {{value}} //How to get it
  </div>
</template>
```

**Child Component:**

```vue
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <p>This {{value}} is 123</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return { value: 123 }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if you have multiple children? what's value you expect to get?

Comment: I fix it clearer @Ben. I want to get VALUE data from CHILD components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ways you can achieve this include:

- You can access the child VM directly via a ref, but this gets hairy because the ref won't be populated until the child component has mounted, and `$refs` isn't reactive, meaning you'd have to do something hacky like this:

  ```html
  <template>
    <div class="parent">
      <child ref="child"></child>
      <template v-if="mounted">{{ $refs.child.value }}</template>
    </div>
  </template>
  ```

  ```js
  data() {
    return {
      mounted: false
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.mounted = true;
  }
  ```
- `$emit` the value from within the child component so that the parent can obtain the value when it is ready or whenever it changes.
- Use [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) (or similar principles) to share state across components.
- Redesign the components so that the data you want is owned by the parent component and is passed down to the child via a prop binding.
- (Advanced) Use [portal-vue](https://github.com/LinusBorg/portal-vue) plugin when you want to have fragments of a component's template to exist elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you think what is the best way among these your ways?

Comment: Ideally you should try to avoid accessing data from a child component (it makes reasoning about the flow of data more difficult in your app), but I suppose #2 is the best way for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you I will choose #2. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Child components pass data back up the hierarchy by emitting events.

For example, in the parent, listen for an event and add the child value to a local one (an array for multiple child elements would be prudent), eg

```
<child @ready="childVal => { value.push(childVal) }"></child>
```

and in the child component, `$emit` the event on creation / mounting, eg

```
mounted () {
  this.$emit('ready', this.value)
}
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/p2jojsrn/

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: {{value}} print [123] instead of 123. How can I fix it @Phil

Comment: @FeedGit well yeah, I did say it was an array (in case you have multiple child components)